# Make a phone call automatic in Windows phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an application to check a call function on Windows phone. I know of this method `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("phone number", "display name");` It requires that a user click on the Call button.

My question is this:

**How can I make a phone call automatically without click call button and check if the phone call pass or fail? Many thank for help!**

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to actually start the call in a RT app. You can try looking for ways to skip that such as finding parallel API's to Touch Injection that work for windows phone.